# How can I create a dot plot of genes and taxonomies with dots scaled to the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a dot plot of genes and taxonomies from metagenome data and I would like the dots to be scaled to the values of the data (gene abundance). How can I do this? I'm still pretty new to R, so I may be missing something obvious.

I've tried using ggdotplot but I'm not sure how to make it work with multiple columns of data. I've tried using pivot_longer but it gives an error:

```
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• call = call
```

If ggdotplot would work to make this kind of figure (reference photo included), how can I indicate that I would like the x axis to be the names of each column? (The y axis will be the row names, so that should be simple). The dots will be the gene abundance values for each set. Part of data table is included as a photo.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Some code with what you've tried so far, as well as a sample dataset that we can work with would be useful. So far, I'm thinking that `geom_point` can get the job done, where `aes(size = value)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to find another method that worked well, it just required a lot of data reformatting, which I was originally trying to avoid. For others to reference: https://davemcg.github.io/post/lets-plot-scrna-dotplots/#moonshot

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help if you provide a sample of your data using `dput()`. In such absence, I'll create a random data set.

```
mydf <- data.frame(cats = LETTERS[1:5], other_cats = LETTERS[6:15]) |> 
  expand.grid()

mydf$value <- rnorm(100, 25, 10)

library(ggplot2)

mydf |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = cats, y = other_cats, size = value, colour = other_cats)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]